# Area where a polynomial in several variables is non-negative

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Clearly, the set $\{x: P(x) \geq 0 \}$ consists of a finite union of intervals for the polynomial function

$P(x) = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n x^n$ with $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is there a similar result for a polynomial in several variables, i.e., a function $P: \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}$ with

$P(x_1,\ldots, x_k) = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n x_1^{b_n^1}\cdots x_k^{b_n^k}$ with $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$

In particular, I would be interested in a result that states that

$A = \{ x: P(x) \geq 0\} = \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$

where the $A_i$ are connected, closed sets in $\mathbb{R}^k$ with the cardinality of $I$ being at most countable (preferably finite).

I see that the regions must be connected and closed (by continuity) and they are separated from $A^c$ by the curve $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^k: P(x) = 0 \}$, but I am somewhat lost on the issue of the cardinality of $I$.

Comment: Your set $A$ is an example of a [semi algebraic set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semialgebraic_set). It can be shown that any such set can be decomposed as a finite [CW complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex) and this implies it has finitely many connected components.  Unfortunately, I can't think of an easy direct proof of this fact.

Comment: Correction: on second thoughts, the cell decomposition you get for semialgebraic sets isn't always a CW complex, but it is finite and the cells are connected, so it does give your result.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply! Could you maybe point me to a reference, where I can find the result on the cell decomposition and the fact that cells are connected sets? Unfortunately, this is not my area at all.

Comment: The general subject area is called [real algebraic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_algebraic_geometry) (although that Wikipedia page isn't very good apart from the links and references).  I recommend the books  *Real Algebraic Geometry* by Bochnak, Coste and Roy and *Tame topology and o-minimal structures* by van den Dries.

Comment: The cell decomposition in question is called the cylindrical algebraic decomposition and I've found an online reference  [here](http://gcomte.perso.math.cnrs.fr/M2/CosteIntroToSemialGeo.pdf).